# Two tables in one view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two table views in one viewController and a menu button.
Initially only tableView1 is displayed, when I press menu button the second table view should appear and the tableView1 is still there.

I was reading about and I implemented what I found, but without results.

Both table view appears, but data are the same and I don't want this. I was trying to do like this :

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    tableView.hidden = NO;
    tableViewMenu.hidden = YES;

    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableViewMenu.delegate = self;
    tableViewMenu.dataSource = self;    
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (tableView == tableView) {
        return 30;
    }        
    else { 
        return 4;
    }        
}

- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (tableView == tableView) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"Cell1";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1] ;
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = @"Table 1";
        NSLog(@"1here is%i  %@",indexPath.row,cell.textLabel.text);
        return cell;
    } else {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2] ;
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = @"Table 2";
        return cell;
    }
}


int i = 1;
- (void) showMenu {
    //slide the content view to the right to reveal the menu
    //tableView.hidden = NO;
    tableViewMenu.hidden = NO;

    NSLog(@"Display");

    if (i == 1) {
        [UITableView animateWithDuration:.25
                              animations:^{
                                  [tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(tableViewMenu.frame.size.width, tableView.frame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.frame.size.height)];
                                  [testView setFrame:CGRectMake(tableViewMenu.frame.size.width, testView.frame.origin.y, testView.frame.size.width, testView.frame.size.height)];

         }];    
         i = 0;        

    } else {          
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.25
                         animations:^{
                             [tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, tableView.frame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.frame.size.height)];
                             [testView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, testView.frame.origin.y, testView.frame.size.width, testView.frame.size.height)];
                             tableViewMenu.hidden=YES;

        }];
        i = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess the problem is the line :

```
if(tableView==tableView)
```

You should compare the `tableview` arguments with your `@property`.
If both the arguments and the iVar have the same name, the argument will override your iVar in the method scope.

```
if (tableview == self.tableView)
```

Answer (score 0):

I set for tableview a tag and i did this :

```
if (tableView.tag==0) {
        return 30;
    }

    else { return 4;
    }

}
```

Idem is for cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: You really should not use tag when it's not needed (here you already had properties connected to your tableviews).The code is much less readable and it adds unnecessary complexity.
Tag should be use when you can't have properties (for exemple if you generate your view in code)

Answer (score 0):

You have to have 2 table views:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView* firstTableView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView* secondTableView;
```

When you press menu button you should change the delegate like this:

```
self.firstTableView.hidden = FALSE;
self.secondTableView.hidden = TRUE;
[self.firstTableView reloadData]
self.firstTableView.dataSource = self;
self.firstTableView.delegate = self;
```

or

```
self.firstTableView.hidden = TRUE;
self.secondTableView.hidden = FALSE;
[self.secondTableView reloadData] 
self.secondTableView.dataSource = self;
self.secondTableView.delegate = self;
```

And in TableView Data Source:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

if (tableView == self.firstTableView)  {
...
}

} else if (tableView == self.secondTableView){
...
}
```

And

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView == self.firstTableView)  {
return 30;
    } else if (tableView == self.secondTableView){
return 4;
}
```